# Problem displaying toast message using json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, toast

I'm trying to implement an ajax form checking where a toast message should appear upon an error. this is the part of toast message section which I am suppose to trigger looks like

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade show {{ session()->get('dismiss', '') }}" data-auto-dismiss="2000">
  <i class="fas fa-times-circle toast-icon"></i>
  <div class="toast-message">{{ $errors->has('message') ? $errors->first('message', ':message') : __('The given data was invalid.') }}</div>
  <i class="fal fa-times close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></i>
</div>
@endif
```

this file is then included into a div i've placed within the body of my html using `<div class="alert-container">@include('frontend.layout.toast-message')</div>`

and on my js side, the ajax function I'm calling.

```
$('#signup_form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: $('#signup_form').attr('action'),
    data: new FormData($('#signup_form')[0]),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      $(this).find('button').prop('disabled', true);
      $.each($('.form-group.is-invalid .message'), function () {
        $(this).text('');
      });
      $.each($('.form-group.is-invalid'), function () {
        $(this).removeClass('is-invalid');
      });
    }
  }).done(function (response) {
    if (response.success == true) {
      ///
    }
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR) {
        if (jqXHR.responseJSON) {
            //prompt for alert message
            var alertContainer = $('.alert-container');
            alertContainer.find('.toast-message').text(jqXHR.responseJSON.message).addClass('show');
            alert(jqXHR.responseJSON.message);
            //go through each input to see which ones are within the error
            $.each(jqXHR.responseJSON.errors, function (field, message) {
                var element = $('#'+ field);
                element.parents('.form-group').addClass('is-invalid');
                element.parents('.form-group').find('.message').text(message).show();
            });
        }
        $(this).find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    })
});
```

the alert returns the message that I should get on my toast message, however the toast doesn't get displayed. It would be good to know what have gone wrong in the code or if I should be parsing the error message in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the `@if .. @endif` is not js code, is php code. So, if you refreshed the page without error it wont exists.

So, I guess this won't find anything:

```
alertContainer.find('.toast-message');
```

**Possible Solution**

Always put the `div.alert` there, but keep it hidden if there isn't any error. Example (I didn't test it):

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade {{ $errors->any()?'show':'hide' }} {{ session()->get('dismiss', '') }}" data-auto-dismiss="2000">
  <i class="fas fa-times-circle toast-icon"></i>
  <div class="toast-message">{{ $errors->has('message') ? $errors->first('message', ':message') : __('The given data was invalid.') }}</div>
  <i class="fal fa-times close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: So how will I need to let my `.alert-container` to know that there is `$error` in order to display the message?